# Best way to handle mutable fields while making a class Immutable

Tags: java, serialization, clone

I want to make Footballer class immutable, it has Address field which is mutable, so what is the best way to make it immutable,

Typically for HomeAddress and Area,I can use

1. Clone
2. Serialization
3. Copy Constructor

Since clone is broken,How to chose between copy constructor or Serialization.

```
package com.javaeight;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ImmutableDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String name = "ronaldo";
        int age = 27;

        List<String> clubs = new ArrayList<>();
        clubs.add("MU");
        clubs.add("BC");
        Area area = new Area(22, 11);
        HomeAddress address = new HomeAddress("Bangalore", "India", area);
        Footballer footballer = new Footballer(name, age, clubs, address);

    }
}


final class Footballer {

    private final String name;
    private final int age;
    private final List<String> clubs;
    private final HomeAddress address;


    public Footballer(String name, int age, List<String> clubs, HomeAddress homeAddress) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.clubs = new ArrayList<>(clubs);
        this.address = new HomeAddress(homeAddress.getCity(), homeAddress.getCountry(), homeAddress.getArea());

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public List<String> getClubs() {
        return new ArrayList<>(clubs);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Footballer{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", clubs=" + clubs +
                '}';
    }
}

class HomeAddress {

    private String city;
    private String country;
    private Area area;

    public HomeAddress(String city, String country, Area area) {
        this.city = city;
        this.country = country;
        this.area = area;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public Area getArea() {
        return area;
    }
}

class Area {

    private int Street;
    private int buildingNumber;


    public Area(int street, int buildingNumber) {
        Street = street;
        this.buildingNumber = buildingNumber;
    }

    public int getStreet() {
        return Street;
    }

    public int getBuildingNumber() {
        return buildingNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: An immutable class does not have mutable fields. A shallow-immutable class may had mutable fields, but they can't be modified by the client. *Any* state may be transfered via a copy constructor, immutable or not. You can also deserialize immutable data. I'm not understanding your question.

Comment: sorry i corrected the question..

Comment: The edit doesn't explain your situation. Like I said, deserializaztion & copy constructors don't change anything in terms of immutability/mutability. Are you referring to singletons? Because a singleton can't be deserialized or copied (since there should always be one instance, and copying/deserializing implies potential for multiple instances), which sounds more like what your post is relating to.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I have updated the question with code, pls revisit

Comment: May be this can help - https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-create-an-immutable-class-in-java

Comment: @MukeshKeshu In that example, they just create object and sets fields and return, that is not the right way, we are acutally binding our class with that..

Comment: **GOOD:** Since you make a new copy of `clubs`, clients can't mutate the clubs. **GOOD:** Since you make a new `HomeAdress`, clients can't mutate the `HomeAddress` object via `Footballer`. **BAD:** Clients can still modify `HomeAddress`; clients can modify the `Area` that was passed to `HomeAddress`. Since clients can still mutate the `Area` that is passed into the address, `Footballer` is only shallowly immutable, with your current code. Make a copy of `Area` (via constructor, similar to other copies), and clients won't be able to mutate the state of `Footballer`, making it fully immutable.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I understand that i have to make them immutable, but should i do copy constructor or should i do serialization??? If I do field by field copy then m class is actually tied with area class..so how to understand this tradeoff